# Whether the word "furn" in English language is meaningful or not?

Tags: meaning

whether the word Furn meaningful or not?

Comment: I've only ever come across one example of a 'definition' being 'apparently a meaningless word'. And the dictionary rectified that in later editions. A candidate is either a word or not (though admittedly there is a grey area in between where informed opinion is divided). Are you asking "Is 'furn' in the English lexicon?" Have you checked online? // Lexico says it's an abbreviation for 'furniture'. How acceptable it is to use it depends on context.

Comment: in one of the competitive exam conducted in India they mentioned this English word "Furn" and asked whether it is meaningful word or not

Comment: not in a context they asked ..just gave this single word itself and asked whether it is the meaningful one

Comment: Was the word written or spoken in the exam? Are we overlooking something obvious here?!

Comment: "Is 'furn' a meaningful word?" is a poorly constructed question. _All_ words are meaningful. And "This English word 'furn' – is it a meaningful word?" is totally unacceptable as it begs the question (and quite possibly with an incorrect premise). // Bottom line: 'furn' is considered by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/furn.) to be an abbreviation. It is a meaningful term. It is probably best not considered a true word. Care should be taken in using it; it might not be acceptable in some contexts.